# Paste PDF file with Pastespecial

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

Here is my code which is copying and paste a PDF Inside an Excel Sheet.

But ! After import the PDF, there is a date value in Excel.
It's 02/01/2019 in the PDF, and change to 01/02/2019 in excel.
I think it is a format problem ? But change the "01/02/2019" to date after the import is useless… it will still be the wrong date.

```
Option Explicit
Sub pdf_to_excel_adobe()

Dim myWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim adobeReaderPath As String
Dim pathAndFileName As String
Dim shellPathName As String

Set myWorksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Adobe Reader")

myWorksheet.Cells.Clear

adobeReaderPath = "C:\AcroRd32.exe"
pathAndFileName = "Z:\TS.pdf"
shellPathName = adobeReaderPath & " """ & pathAndFileName & """"

Call Shell( _
    pathname:=shellPathName, _
    windowstyle:=vbNormalFocus)

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:03")

SendKeys "%vpc"
SendKeys "^a"
SendKeys "^c"

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:30")

Windows("NTT.xlsm").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Adobe Reader").Activate
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Call Shell("TaskKill /F /IM AcroRd32.exe", vbHide)

End Sub
```

Comment: Change the number format of the cell where you paste the date to "text"  *before* you paste: `Range(…).NumberFormat = "@"`

Comment: It doesn't change… ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Adobe Reader").Activate
Range("A1").Select
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "@"
ActiveSheet.Paste.

Comment: will the date be in A1? Or in another cell?

Comment: An idiot mistake sorry… Thank you for your help, it works !